# scrollVIew.fullScroll(HorizontalScrollView.FOCUS_RIGHT) doesn't scroll to end

Tags: android, kotlin, horizontalscrollview, kotlin-android-extensions

I'm making simple calculator, with similar design to Google's calculator. I have text with calculations inside HorizontalScrollView, and i want it to scroll to the end of calculation when typing. I already did this with this code (Kotlin):

```
textView.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {

        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
            scrollVIew.fullScroll(HorizontalScrollView.FOCUS_RIGHT)
        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}
        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}
    })
```

And here is .xml fragment with scrollView:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollVIew"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
        android:textSize="75sp" />
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

And this kinda works, text scrolls to one before last chater when text updates, but not last. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a `post` to do the fullScroll:

```
textView.post { scrollVIew.fullScroll(HorizontalScrollView.FOCUS_RIGHT) }
```

It's because in the `afterTextChanged` callback, the textView's text is not finished changing, so you should use a `post` to do the scroll in the next runloop.